# keep getting 'client' method undefined when running rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-platform, rubygems

trying to add this to my rails project https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client

so i first obviously bundle installed the gem, then i created a parse.rb file in config/initializers with this code :

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

client = Parse.create :application_id => 'API_KEY',
                      :api_key        => 'API_KEY',
```

when i call client anywhere i get a error that its undefined

Answer (score 0):

In your example `client` is a local variable. By the time you try to access it, it has already left the scope. What you should do is create or use a globally visible object. One example:

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

::MyParse = Parse.create :application_id => 'APP_ID',
                         :api_key        => 'API_KEY',
```

You can access such object as `MyParse` in the code.

Another example:

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

MyApp::Application.configure do
   config.parse = Parse.create :application_id => 'APP_ID',
                               :api_key        => 'API_KEY',
end
```

And use it like this:

```
MyApp::Application.config.parse
```

Comment: So what your saying is make it global so i can use it anywhere? also how would i use it to get data then?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to get data'? I gave two examples of how to access your object.

Comment: so how would i use MyParse? put it in a controller?

Comment: You can access MyParse as described in any place of your code since it is defined in global namespace. It will be available by this name in controllers, models, helpers, etc.

Comment: so basically i would use MyParse in replace of Client as i was before?

Comment: something like this? game_score = MyParse.object("GameScore")

Comment: getting this now, undefined method `create' for Parse:Module (NoMethodError)